# "Read-Only Region" Visual Studio 2008 options

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, region

[Extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478135/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-region-of-code-read-only-in-visual-studio)

In Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors, If you choose to "Show settings for" Text Editor and look in the Display items dialog it says there' a "Read-Only" region you can set the font for.

I'm not sure what's that for?  Where do you encounter the read-only regions this dialog wants to set the font for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the help file:

> **Read-Only Region**: Code that cannot be edited. For example code displayed in the Code Definition View window or code that cannot be modified during Edit and Continue.